# Update too many columns in mssql using Node.Js

Tags: sql, node.js, sql-server, node-mssql

I been working with Node js and SQL server for the last 3 weeks using all kinds of operations on the database but when I trying to update too many columns values(18 columns) it ain't working, can any one explain why is that happening?

Node.Js code:

```
new sql.Request(pool1).input('sellerId', sql.VarChar(100), postData.sellerId)
            .input('streetNum', sql.VarChar(45), postData.streetNum)
            .input('buildingNum', sql.VarChar(45), postData.buildingNum)
            .input('apartmentNum', sql.VarChar(45), postData.apartmentNum)
            .input('town', sql.VarChar(45), postData.town)
            .input('governance', sql.VarChar(45), postData.governance)
            .input('floorNum', sql.VarChar(45), postData.floorNum)
            .input('poBox', sql.VarChar(45), postData.poBox)
            .input('zipCode', sql.Int(), parseInt(postData.zipCode))
            .input('creditInfo', sql.VarChar(45), postData.creditInfo)
            .query('update Seller set street# = @streetNum, building#             =                @buildingNum, apartment# = @apartmentNum, town = @town, governance = @governance, floor# = @floorNum, PO_box = @poBox, zip_code = @zipCode, credit_info = @creditInfo where seller_id = @sellerId', (err, result1) => {
              if (!err) {
                console.log(result1.rowsAffected);
                res.json({
                  updateState: true,
                  resultt: result1.rowsAffected
                });
              } else {
                console.log(err);
                res.json({
                  updateState: false,
                  resultt: result.rowsAffected
                });
              }
            });
```

database DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE Seller(
seller_id varchar(100) not null,
seller_email  VARCHAR(45) not null unique,
brand_name  VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL unique,
first_name  VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
last_name  VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
password  VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
phone_number  VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
profile_image varchar(200)NULL,
street#  VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
building#  VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
apartment#  VARCHAR(45) NULL,
town  VARCHAR(45) not NULL,
governance  VARCHAR(45) NULL,
floor# VARCHAR(45) NULL,
PO_box VARCHAR(45) NULL,
zip_code int NOT NULL,
credit_info  VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (seller_id));
```

database DML:

```
insert into Seller(seller_id,seller_email,brand_name,first_name,last_name,password  
     ,phone_number,street#,building#,apartment#,town,governance,floor#  ,PO_box 
    ,zip_code,credit_info,profile_image)
    values('mosta.amer@gmail.com','.IDEA','Mostafa' ,'amer','12345678','0787375793','45p','2','2','moqabalain','Amman', '2' ,'amman/46','123456','visa','https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/         e-commerceasdasdasdasd-      c6abd.appspot.com/o/Products%2Fmosta.amer%40gmail.com%2Fic_launcher.png?alt=media&token=41a8db11-42d3-493a-874d-2ef74aba5b74')
```

Comment: Please, show us your code and the error you get. What exactly is not working?

Comment: I edit it, and it didn't give me any error,the query executes with no errors but none of these records affected with the update @PavelSmirnov